# Custom Filter Tag Result Page

Tags: tags, content-filtering

I would like to change the behaviour of the Filter on the Joomla Tag Result page. When you search for certain Tags it will give you a list with article. If you than apply a Filter, which is a textbox, you can only Filter by Article Title. What i want to do is to change it to a Select Box with more Tags and so the Filter applied will only show the Articles containing this Tag also.

I have searched for the Code, but don't know how to alter it and if it is the correct code. How to create a select Box with values i know, i just don't know how to change the Title Filter to a "Tag Filter"

I believe this is the code which has to be modified:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('filter_field')) :?>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="filter-search-lbl element-invisible" for="filter-search">
                <?php echo JText::_('COM_TAGS_TITLE_FILTER_LABEL').'&#160;'; ?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="filter-search" id="filter-search" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->state->get('list.filter')); ?>" class="inputbox" onchange="document.adminForm.submit();" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_TAGS_FILTER_SEARCH_DESC'); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('COM_TAGS_TITLE_FILTER_LABEL'); ?>" />
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This code snippet i took from the default_items.php. (I assume this is correct)
Anybody has an idea on how to make such a change?